# javafx MediaPlayer not playing audio

Tags: java, audio, javafx, javafx-8, media-player

In my JavaFX application, I have the following code placed in a method. My goal is to play `url`'s audio, where `url` is an `http` link to an MP4 file.

```
Media media = new Media(url);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
```

When I call the method, nothing plays, but I do not get an error. Also, when checking `mediaPlayer`'s status using `mediaplayer.getStatus()`, I get `UNKNOWN`. When I add a `MediaView`, like this:

```
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
grid.add(mediaView, 0, 0);
```

The audio and video play. However I don't want the video to play, so I want to avoid the extra overhead using `MediaView`.

If I make `MediaPlayer` a static variable, the audio plays, but I would rather not use a static variable. Why does the initial code not work?

Comment: Where did you call mediaPlayer.play()? The status `UNKNOWN` is for showing that the player is not already loaded and set up completly. Where do you get the status? After play method and after waiting some seconds?

Comment: I have a hard time believing that just making `mediaPlayer` static would change its behavior.  Have you checked `mediaPlayer.getError()` when the status is UNKNOWN?  Have you verified that `url` is valid (such as by trying to download from it directly)?

Comment: @NwDx I don't have to call `mediaPlayer.play()` since it is set to autoplay. This code is in an external class, and I run it from my main `Application` class by instantiating an object of the external class.

Comment: @VGR  `mediaPlayer.getError()` returns `null`. Also, I am sure the url is valid. (After all, it works with the static `MediaPlayer`.)

Comment: @Kootling autoPlay Property and play() are called on the READY state of the mediaplayer, and if the player never reaches this state and if it works as static, well I think it's a threading issue, since play() is synchronized. From which thread you are calling/creating the new media player?

Comment: If you’re creating the MediaPlayer in a static field, that means you’re also initializing the URL differently, unless it’s in a static field in both cases.  I would print it out when creating the MediaPlayer non-statically, just to be sure.

Comment: @VGR `getError()` returns `null` in both cases. What do you mean by "initializing the URL differently"? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @NwDx I am not manually multithreading, so it should be run in the same thread as the main Application.

Comment: @Kootling Can you please add the whole code in context of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is clearly something wrong with the MediaPlayer in JavaFX, and has been for years. Nonetheless, there are workarounds.

One workaround is this: When creating your user interface, create a MediaViewer component. Even if you do not include it in your layout, declare it as an object attribute, so that it is ready and available.

```
private MediaView viewer = new MediaView();
```

Then: When you want to play an audio file, attach your MediaPlayer to the MediaView component before calling the "play" method.

```
viewer.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
```

This seems to cause the audio clips to play properly.

Comment: hmm ... why would you instantiate anything you are not (or only maybe) going to use?

Comment: Because it works? It's a workaround. If you declare everything inside a method, the MediaPlayer does not play clips correctly, at least, not on the first attempt. Declaring either the MediaPlayer or the MediaView at the class level seems to solve this problem.

Comment: yeah, you need a reference that survives potential gc - but that doesn't mean to really _instantiate_ it: we can have the reference on the instance level and set it only when needed.